# What does this mean and how to fix citus error?

Tags: postgresql, citus

For the query:

```
SELECT
    cu.id id,
    cu.email email,
    SUM(case when(rt.type = 'credit' and ( re.type = 'account_refilling' OR re.type = 'site_publishing' OR re.type = 'tariff_buying' )) then rt.amount else 0 end ) transactions_sum
  FROM client_users cu
  LEFT JOIN referral_accounts ra ON ra.owner_id = cu.id
  LEFT JOIN referral_transactions rt ON rt.account_id = ra.id
  LEFT JOIN referral_events re ON re.id = rt.event_id
  GROUP BY cu.id, cu.email
  ORDER BY transactions_sum DESC
```

I got error:

```
Shards of relations in outer join queries must have 1-to-1 shard partitioning
```

What does this mean and what I should do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should distribute your tables with same method and they should have same shards count